# not able to get proper output for sed command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, centos

I have one file named `WSH.txt` in which I am having content -

```
"WSH"."WSH_INTERFACE_ERRORS"
```

So here what exactly I need is that - `"WSH"."` should get replaced by blank space.

So now I have created one script named `sed.sh` in which I have given -

```
SUBSTR=$(echo $1 | cut -d'.' -f 1)

sed -i 's/"$SUBSTR"."/ /g' $1
```

But when I am trying to run `./sed.sh WSH.txt`, I am getting output -

```
# cat WSH.txt
"WSH"."WSH_INTERFACE_ERRORS"
```

(Sorry I was unable to add image here)

But the output which I want is -

WSH_INTERFACE_ERRORS

I also tried with -

```
sed -i 's/"${SUBSTR}"."/ /g' $1
```

But still it's not giving the result.

can someone please help me with this ?!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read how to post questions and try to make your future question more readable instead of just copying code without any syntax highlighting or paragraphs.

Comment: Also, show us what output you are getting, and what you want it to be. This needs clarification.

Comment: Thank you @agentsmith for your suggestion I will keep this in mind while posting a question!.
Thank you once again!

Comment: Yes @PaulHodges , I have edited my question, and I have given what output I am getting and output I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT

I read that entirely wrong.

Assuming quotes are IN the file itself...
The variable was inside single quotes and so not being parsed.

Make sure you get the quote at the end, too.

```
sed -i '/"'"$SUBSTR"'"[.]"/{ s/"//g; s/'"$SUBSTR"'[.]/ /; }' $1
```

This scans for lines matching the desired pattern, ignoring all others.
ON A MATCH, it

- eliminates all double-quotes from the file with the first s///
- then closes the singles so the second double-quotes can properly quote your variable in case there is embedded spaces or such,
- then closes the double quoting after the variable,
- opens single quotes again,
- bracket-quotes the literal dot you want to match,
- then ends the search pattern and replaces it with the space.

### Original (wrong) answer

---

If I'm reading it right, you're doing a lot of work to accomplish this:

```
sed -Ei 's/[^ ]+[.]//' WSH.txt
```

The problem preventing it from working is the double quotes that aren't being matched. You included them as part of the pattern.

```
sed -i 's/"$SUBSTR"."/ /g' $1 # sub "WSH"<anychar>", not what you want.
       ^  ^       ^ ^    ^
```

The doubles are inside singles, so they got passed to sed as literal characters.
I think the line you are looking for is one of these:

```
sed -i "s/$SUBSTR[.]/ /g" $1 # double quotes around the whole pattern
```

or

```
sed -i 's/'"$SUBSTR"'[.]/ /g' $1 # switching quotes
```

or even, for this case,

```
sed -i s/"$SUBSTR"'[.]/ /g' $1 # only quote what needs it
```

In either case, what you are actually doing is building the pattern as a string on the command line, then passing it to `sed`. The quotes aren't *for* `sed` - they are so the command parser gets the string right *before* passing it to `sed`, which should never see them unless they are *intended* to be included as part of the pattern.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax is `sed` BRE syntax.
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#ERE-syntax is `sed` ERE syntax.
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html is `bash` Quoting.

Comment: Hm. Quotes are in the file, aren't they? Editing.

Comment: Hey  Paul Hodges! I have one doubt here.....actually in my file their are other words also which starts with " (Quotes). So I dont want all to get replaced. I only want that pattern ("$SUBSTR".")  to get replaced !
Can you please help me with this?!

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes. :)

Comment: Added matching line selection - a built-in `grep` in the `sed` code. Try now.

Comment: Hey @Paul Hodges. If I am adding some other words before that  "WSH"."WSH_INTERFACE_ERRORS"
Then its not working it seems, like for example if I am giving -
The "WSH"."WSH_INTERFACE_ERRORS"   , then its not working it seems.
It is giving me output same as it is - 

The "WSH"."WSH_INTERFACE_ERRORS"

So,what should I add in sed command  to make it work
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show me lines of the file you're editing. I used the example you gave. the `^` in the match requires it be at the beginning of the line. I'll take that out and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Hodges, It worked for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do the replacement in one command:

```
sed 's/"WSH"."/ /g' WSH.txt
```

output:(SPACE)WSH_INTERFACE_ERRORS"
Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Thank you @FEIdin for your response, actually I am not passing WSH.txt 
I am passing it dynamically that is $f. 
So thats why it will not work for me

Comment: Well @saurabh704 : for f in *; do ; sed 's/"WSH"."/ /g' $f ; done will also do it. The point is either you are doing a lot of work for a simple task, or the question is not clear. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @FEldin for you respopnse. Actually here I am not creating script based one file , WSH.txt only.....I have to pass their dynamically n no of files with the help of for loop.  Thats why I was facing difficulty. 
Now here for question purpose I have mention here one file name only.